# How to interpret the output of R's glmer() with quadratic terms

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I want to use quadratic terms to fit my general linear mixed model with id as a random effect, using the lme4 package. It's about how the distance to settlements influences the probability of occurrence of an animal. I use the following code (I hope it is correct):

```
glmer_dissettl <- glmer(case ~ poly(dist_settlements,2) + (1|id), data=rsf.data, family=binomial(link="logit"))

summary(glmer_dissettl)
```

I get the following output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: case ~ poly(dist_settlements, 2) + (1 | id)
   Data: rsf.data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  6179.2   6205.0  -3085.6   6171.2     4654 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.14647 -0.90518 -0.04614  0.94833  1.66806 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.02319  0.1523  
Number of obs: 4658, groups:  id, 18

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 0.02684    0.04905   0.547    0.584    
poly(dist_settlements, 2)1 37.94959    2.41440  15.718   <2e-16 ***
poly(dist_settlements, 2)2 -1.28536    2.28040  -0.564    0.573    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) p(_,2)1
ply(ds_,2)1 0.083         
ply(ds_,2)2 0.067  0.150
```

I don't know exactly how to interpret this, especially with the two lines for poly(dist_settlements,2). Next to understanding, I also wanna see if the quadratic term is making the model better than the basic model without it.

The output of the basic model without a quadratic term:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
  (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: case ~ scale(dist_settlements) + (1 | id)
   Data: rsf.data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  6177.5   6196.9  -3085.8   6171.5     4655 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6009 -0.8998 -0.0620  0.9539  1.6417 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.02403  0.155   
Number of obs: 4658, groups:  id, 18

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              0.02873    0.04945   0.581    0.561
scale(dist_settlements)  0.55936    0.03538  15.810   <2e-16
                           
(Intercept)                
scale(dist_settlements) ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
scl(dst_st) 0.077
```

I appreciate every tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points.

- Coefficients of non-linear model terms do not have a straightforward interpretation and you should make effect plots to be able to communicate the results from your analyses. You may use `effectPlotData()` from the `GLMMadaptive` package to do this. Refer to [this page](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/reference/effectPlotData.html) for more information.
- To be able to appraise whether including a quadratic effect of `dist_settlements` improves the model fit, you should fit a model *without* the squared term (i.e. only the linear effect of `dist_settlements`) and a model *with* the squared term. Then perform a likelihood ratio test to appraise whether inclusion of complex terms improves the model fit. In case of LMMs, make sure to fit both models using maximum likelihood, *not* REML. For GLMMs, you don't have to borther about (RE)ML.
- The variance of the random intercepts is rather close to 0, which may require your attention. Refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115180/253683) and [this section](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1) of Ben Bolker's github for more information on this topic.

You may want to take a look at [this great lecture series](https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf) by Dimitris Rizopoulos for more information on (G)LMMs.

Comment: Thank you, I am working with a glmm for the first time, and it's a lot to look out for. Now I know better what to do. I will start plotting right away. If I understood it correctly the glmer() is only using ML. Only for lmer () I remembered the option of specifying REML = FALSE or TRUE.

Comment: I have edited the answer and included a couple of words about REML/ML as well as a link to some great lecture series.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. It helped a lot!